# How to aggregate object properties after filtering in ng-repeat angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.2.16 and filtering a list of objects like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter:query)">
  {{item.title}}
</li>
```

lets say I have the "items" array below

```
var items = [ { title: "foo", priority: 1 },
              { title: "bar", priority: 2 },
              { title: "bla", priority: 1 } ];
```

and after being filtered with "b", angular sets "filteredItems" to

```
filteredItems == [ { title: "bar", priority: 2 },
                   { title: "bla", priority: 1 } ];
```

What I'm looking to do is count the occurrences of each priority type, post-filter, and print them out. E.g. the output given the above scenario would print `priority-1 = 2, priority-2 = 1` and then becomes `priority-1 = 1, priority-2 = 1` after the filter "b" is applied.

How should I do this in angular?

I tried creating a new controller and then using `$scope.$parent.filteredItems` but the filteredItems piece doesn't update dynamically.

Here's a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/uA5TgBVFVEd89dHSP0Yo

Comment: Check `$watch` and you don't need another 2 controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post by Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2592-hooking-into-the-complete-event-of-an-ngrepeat-loop-in-angularjs.htm) came closest to answering my question by adding a custom directive that fires an event after ng-repeat completes. However, it was a bit more complex than I wanted.

My final approach was to add a custom $filter to the controller, which is triggered when the input changes, and finally creates a summary object that I can print out. The plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJoK4NVxONnNSz75Wnj3?p=preview).

The HTML:

```
    <input ng-model="query" type="text" ng-change="myFilter(query)" />

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <pre>{{item}}</pre></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Summary of items</h3>
    <p >
      Priority-1: {{summary.p1}}<br>
      Priority-2: {{summary.p2}}
    </p>

  </body>
```

The App.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter',
  function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.originalItems = [{
      title: "foo",
      priority: 1
    }, {
      title: "bar",
      priority: 2
    }, {
      title: "bla",
      priority: 1
    }];

    $scope.items = $scope.originalItems;

    var summarize = function(items) {
      var summary = {
        p1: 0,
        p2: 0
      };
      for (var i in items) {
        switch (items[i].priority) {
          case 1:
            summary.p1++;
            break;
          case 2:
            summary.p2++;
            break;
        }
      }
      return summary;
    };

    $scope.myFilter = function(query) {
      $scope.items = $filter('myFilter')($scope.originalItems, query);
      $scope.summary = summarize($scope.items);
    }

    $scope.summary = summarize($scope.items);

  }
]);

app.filter('myFilter', ['$filter',
  function($filter) {
    return function(items, query) {
      return $filter('filter')(items, query);
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way, but still not ideal:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wkGKYQus2exkLycIu9XB?p=preview

html:

```
<body ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query" type="text"/>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : query">
      <pre>{{item}}</pre></li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Summary of items</h3>
  <p >
    Priority-1: {{items | filter : query | sumFilter: '1'}}<br>
    Priority-2: {{items | filter : query | sumFilter: '2'}}
  </p>
</body>
```

js:

```
app.filter('sumFilter', function() {
  return function(items, value) {
    var summary = 0; 
    for (var i in items) {
      if (items[i].priority == value) {
        summary++;
      }
    }
    return summary;
  }
});
```